# How to use shortcuts in dockable windows?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, .net, ux

I have developed a custom dockable window with textboxes, comboboxes and buttons for use in ArcMap. After the user clicks on a button in the dockable window a function is invoked.
How can I invoke the function/button_click-event using short cuts. Where do I have to wire the event?:

```
this.KeyDown +=new KeyEventHandler(MyDockableWindow_KeyDown);
```

Where do I have to impement the event?

```
private void MyDockableWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.F1:
                button1.PerformClick();
                break;
            case Keys.F2:
                button2.PerformClick();
                break;
            case Keys.F3:
                button3.PerformClick();
                break;
            case Keys.F4:
                button4.PerformClick();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two solutions for my question. The first one is to override the ProcessCmdKey method in my DockableWindow class e.g:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.A)) {
        button1.PerformClick();
        return true;
    }
    if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.B)) {
        button3.PerformClick();
        return true;
    }
    if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.C)) {
        button3.PerformClick();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

The second solution is to use the  built-in support for mnemonics in the buttons. Considering a button with a text property like Set&A produces a self-documenting shortcut without needing any code. Operated by the user, in this example, by typing Alt+A.

In both cases the dockable window must have the focus or else it wouldn't work.

Both solutions are inspired by a post of Hans Passant on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468200/key-events-processcmdkey

Answer (score 2):

If your Methods is capsulated to ArcMap Command, you could use AcceleratorTable.

```
IAcceleratorTable pAccTable = m_app.Document.Accelerators;
UID uid = new UIDClass();
//Some command uid
uid.Value = "{E1F29C6B-4E6B-11D2-AE2C-080009EC732A}";
bool addedAcc = pAccTable.Add(uid, System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.A), true, false, false) ;
```

But, if other than the above like you want to execute your own methods, you need to use SetWindowsHookEx win32 api and global hooking keyboards event. This is the sample,

```
public class KeyEventsHooker {

    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT {
        public ushort KeyCode;
        public ushort Scan;
        public uint Flags;
        public uint Time;
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
     CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn,
    IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
     CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
     CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode,
    IntPtr wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam);

    private int hHook = 0;

    public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam);
    public event Action<System.Windows.Forms.Keys> OnKeyDown;

    public void Hook() {

        hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, new HookProc(KeyHookProc), IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    }

    public void Unhook() {

        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    }

    private int KeyHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam) {

        if (nCode < 0) {
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, ref lParam);
        }
        else {

            switch (wParam.ToInt32()) {

                case WM_KEYDOWN:

                    if (OnKeyDown != null) {

                        OnKeyDown((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)lParam.KeyCode);
                    }

                    break;
            }

            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, ref lParam); 
        }
    }
}
```

And, you could hook in your DockableWindow Class like this,

```
public DockableWindow1(object hook) {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Hook = hook;

    _keyEventsHooker = new KeyEventsHooker();
    _keyEventsHooker.Hook();
    _keyEventsHooker.OnKeyDown += new Action<Keys>(_keyEventsHooker_OnKeyDown);
}
```

You should consider that this sample is ignoring such as shift, alt and ctrl keys. But it is not a basis of GIS, so I will omit these parts.

Comment: Darksanta, thank you for your answer. Since the buttons are inside the dochable window (usercontrol), I can not use the ArcGIS shortcuts (IAcceleratorTable). I will give a try to your second solution, to see how it works You wrote that the sample is ignoring keys such as shift, alt and ctrl, which is a disadvantage. I found out an other way to get shortcuts working in the dockable window. I post it as an answer, since I have no possibility to add code blocks to a comment.